# Need to COUNT in LEFT JOIN using MYSQL

Tags: sql, mysql

SELECT * 
    FROM `tbl_group_join` tgj 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_groups tg ON tg.group_id = tgj.group_id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_registeration tr ON tr.mem_id = tgj.mem1_id 
    WHERE tgj.group_id =24 LIMIT 0 , 30

Above query is working right. And it produces two rows as O/P. Exactly this is what I want.

Now in addition I need the count of ROWS. I did it by

```
SELECT count(mem_id)
FROM tbl_group_join 
WHERE group_id = '24' GROUP BY group_id.
```

But it makes the O/P in to one row. That is, I Ihe get O/P in one field as count as 2.

Now I  am in need to get these two results in one QUERY.

Any possibilities

Thanks in Advance

Fero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT count(mem_id)
FROM tbl_group_join 
WHERE group_id = '24' GROUP BY group_id
) as memAmount 
FROM `tbl_group_join` tgj 
LEFT JOIN tbl_groups tg ON tg.group_id = tgj.group_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_registeration tr ON tr.mem_id = tgj.mem1_id 
WHERE tgj.group_id =24 LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: Thanks pixeline.. This is exactly what i want.

Comment: Thanks pixeline. What is this type of query called?

Comment: It's called a subselect, and it is the worst performing way to do this.

Comment: Is there any other way rexem ?

Comment: Yes, use an inline view like what you see in my answer.